# Installing Rails on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, ubuntu-15.10

I'm trying to install Rails on my laptop running Ubuntu 15.10 by using a book called "Beginning Rails 4, 3rd Edition" by Apress.  It uses the rvm method and I just wanted to know if anyone knew of an easier way to install Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the ability of managing multiple ruby versions and gemsets, you can just install ruby using apt

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby
```

Then install rails

```
$ gem install rails
```